# Загрузка файлов на сервер: IO Error в Uploadify

Tags: php, javascript

Приветствую, гуру!

Есть задача сделать загрузку файлов размером до 200мб на сервер сайта (в каталог), реализовал с помощью `Uploadify`, все настройки по увеличению размера закачиваемого файла сделал и в настройках php и в самих настройках `Uplodadify`.

Но при загрузке файла размером примерно от 50 до 200 вылазит ошибка `IO Error`, а файлы до 20 мегабайт грузит нормально, почему? Помогите решить проблему...

Или может дадите какой-нибудь аплоудер рабочий...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <?php $timestamp = time();?>
    $(function() {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'fileSizeLimit' : '204MB',
            'QueueSizeLimit'  :  1 ,
            'buttonText' : 'Загрузить микс...',
            'formData'     : {
                'author' : '<?php echo $author;?>',
                'title' : '<?php echo $title;?>',
                'time_m' : '<?php echo $time_m;?>',
                'style' : '<?php echo $style;?>',
                'quality' : '<?php echo $quality;?>',
                'megab_mix' : '<?php echo $megab_mix;?>',
                'tracklist' : '<?php echo $tracklist;?>',
                'author_page' : '<?php echo $author_page;?>',
                'email' : '<?php echo $email;?>',
                'time_s' : '<?php echo $time_s;?>',
                'unikkod' : '<?php echo $string;?>',
                'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'

            },
            'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
            'uploader' : 'uploadify.php',
            'onQueueComplete' : function(queueData) {
        alert('Поздравляем! Загрузка завершена!');

    }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `$_FILES[]["error"]` какой код выдает?

Comment: он понимаешь грузит мелкие файлы, а вот большие не понятно почему не хочет...

Comment: В любом случае, нужен код ответа сервера. Раз Uplodadify выдает ошибку, то он явно не 200. Вряд ли проблема с самим Uplodadify, скорее всего трабла с настройками хостинга. Если размер post-данных корректный, то не помешает проверить время выполнения скриптов.

`SecFilterEngine` в off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно увеличить максимальный объем поста, загружаемого файла. Создайте в корне .htaccess, с параметрами:

```
php_value  upload_max_filesize  200M   
php_value  post_max_size  200M
```

,если поддерживает хостинг.

Comment: да вот в том то и дело, что это я тоже сделал =/ в корне сайта прописал, думаю в папке где работает сам скрипт нет смысла дать настройки .htaccess

Comment: вот он грузит 15% из 81мб, сбрасывает, потом пытается еще пару раз загрузить и выводит ошибку IO Error =| И че делать не знаю... раньше вроде бы работало =( А может случиться конфликт какой-нибудь при подключенной на странице Jquery?